# How to remove a child node from Python AST parent node with NodeTransformer?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

[image: AST part]

Given a **part** of an AST for some code, I need to remove particular default assignments from function definition. To be specific, I need to remove all the variables that are contained in a list `vars_to_remove` from function definitions where these variables are used as parameter.

For example, take `vars_to_remove = ['sum1']` and a function `def do_smth(sum = sum1):`. Assume `sum1` has been defined globally previously, and added to that list.
I fail to find an way to remove what I want without either removing the whole FunctionDef Node. Or being unable to uniquely identify the node I need to remove. See my attempts below.

I tried to solve the problem in two ways:

**Parent way:**

I override def `visit_FunctionDef(self, node)`, I am able to access the parameter I need to remove. However, if I return None, this will remove the whole FunctionDef node from the tree, because this is the node that is passed in. While I need to only remove all the nodes corresponding to `node.args.defaults[0]...node.args.defaults[n]`.

**Child way:**

I override `visit_Name(self, node)`. When I do that, I am able to return None, removing the node. However, this deals with all Name nodes in the whole code (from which the AST is derived), not the ones defined exclusively within function definitions. I am removing `id:'sum1'`, but I do not need to necessarily remove all of the other occurrences of Name nodes in the whole program where the `id = sum1`!

I think I am missing an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this my modifying the function's arguments in the call to `visit_FunctionDef`:

```py
class Transformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        defaults = node.args.defaults
        # Track args with and without defaults. We want to keep args
        # without defaults. For args with defaults, we need to  sync the
        # defaults to be removed with their corresponding args.
        args_without_defaults = node.args.args[: -len(defaults)]
        args_with_defaults = node.args.args[-len(defaults) :]
        # Filter out unwanted args and defaults.
        retain = [
            (a, d)
            for (a, d) in zip(args_with_defaults, defaults)
            if d.id not in vars_to_remove
        ]
        node.args.args = args_without_defaults + [a for (a, d) in retain]
        node.args.defaults = [d for (a, d) in retain]
        return node
```

Given this source:

```py
def func1(sum=sum1):
    pass

def func2(a=spam, b=sum1):
    pass

def func3(a=spam):
    pass

def func4(a=spam, b=sum1, c=eggs):
    pass
```

this result is output:

```py
def func1():
    pass

def func2(a=spam):
    pass

def func3(a=spam):
    pass

def func4(a=spam, c=eggs):
    pass
```

Comment: thank you very much! Could you suggest good source with explanation of how the ast library works, especially in terms of NodeTransformer, as the documentation is not really exhaustive at all. Also, talking about the code below, do I correctly understand that despite setting nodes to None, it will not really remove them from the tree? 


`for global_var_name in self.global_vars_names:
                for i in range(0, len(node.args.defaults)):
                    if global_var_name == node.args.defaults[i].id:
                        node.args.defaults[i] = None`

Comment: I don't know of any - there might be an assumption that people will have an understanding from compilers courses if they did a comp sci degree. But you can think of the "tree" as being a list of nested lists.  Thus you can add or remove nodes by inserting or removing elements from the lists.  I find it's useful to have a REPL open, and use it to explore interesting nodes.

Comment: The problem with the cod in your comment, I think, is that each "default" corresponds to an "arg".  You need to consider them together.  Also, setting to `None` works for the `visit` methods in `Transformer` classes, but here we are removing subnodes, so we just create a new list of nodes and assign it to the parent attribute.